# Modify remotely ACL several PC

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I want to set some ACL remotely.

The file `test.csv` contains *computer* and *username*. I think the problem is to pass field `$user` inside `Enter-Pssession`:

```
Import-Csv C:\test.csv | ForEach-Object {

Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $Computer
$Path = C:\Users\$User\Desktop
$Acl = Get-Acl 
$Ar = New-Object  system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("$User","ReadAndExecute","ObjectInherit,ContainerInherit","None","Allow")
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl -Path $Path -AclObject $Acl
Exit-PSSession}
```

**Error:**

```
The term 'C:\Users\$User\Desktop' is not recognizaed as the name of a cmdlet, function, script, file or operable program.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to access the current user and computer using the *pipeline* variable of the foreach loop. For example `$_.User` and `$_.Computer`. You could also assign the variables: `$User = $_.User` and `$Computer = $_.Computer`. **Note**: The name of the variable depends on the column name of the csv.

You are also missing the quotes where you assign the path, that is why you get the error message.:

```
$Path = "C:\Users\$User\Desktop"
```